# Simplest way to check edge set for transitivity

Tags: algorithms, graphs, transitivity

I'm playing around with tournaments and currently have the problem that I need to check whether a given subset of the edges of a tournament is transitive (it need not be acyclic). I'm aware that I can always take the transitive closure of the edge set and see whether it terminates without adding a single edge or not, but I was wondering if there might be a simpler way than that.

Note that I'm specifically going for simplicity, not efficiency; the tournaments I want to check are over a maximum of $7$ vertices, so complexity really isn't an issue. I would prefer simple, easy to implement ways. The simplest I could find so far is Floyd-Warshall, but maybe someone knows anything that's simpler still.

Comment: When googling, try "reachability graph".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a very simple algorithm for this:

```
for each edge (u,v) in the graph:
    for each edge (v,w) in the graph:
        if (u,w) is not in the graph, return "Not transitive"
return "Transitive"
```

Basically, if the graph is not transitive, then you can always find some path of length two $u\to v \to w$ such that the edge $u \to w$ is not present in the graph.  If the graph is transitive, there won't be any such path of length 2.  So, just check this condition.

Comment: Yeah that should even be simpler than Floyd-Warshall, I'll probably do this. Cheers!

Comment: Turns out I get to use a library that does matrix multiplication, so I can just take the square of the adjacency matrix and see whether it has any non-zero entries where the original matrix was zero.